# Nginx server not able to serve angular-cli /dist folder

Tags: php, angular, docker, nginx, angular-cli

I have setup angular-js with PHP-laravel application in Docker which is communicating with Nginx server which is another container.

The issue I am facing is, when I load a page I found all teh files under dist folder are rendering as HTML (mostly index.html)

**

> Error log:

**

> - inline.c765f51cc9f6573bab79.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError:    Unexpected token <
> - polyfills.359e94482318a5f6a731.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError:    Unexpected token <
> - main.efdf0cfb43ea8d6546a8.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError:    Unexpected token <

**

> vhost.conf

**

```
server {
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
        root /var/www/public;
        try_files $uri index.html /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
       deny all;
    }


}

server {
   listen         80;
   listen    [::]:80;
   return         301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

I think issue is nginx cant serve these files so it is returning index.html which is breaking in an error.

Thanks, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I think it's because of your `try_files` rules. Can you try it with `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` as suggested in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-servers) please?

Comment: Nope, Not working

Comment: the problem is that, when you serve de bundles files, fall in error and serve a index.html (or an error 404 page), You must allow server serve .js files (Sorry,  I don't know much of Laravel PHP)